# Function that finds smallest m > n such that m and n are not relatively prime

Tags: functional-programming, primes, sml

First off, I'm almost completely new functional programming (and programming in general) so I apologize in advance if this seems like a stupid question. Anyway, I've been doing some programming exercises and done well so far, but this one got me stuck:

I need to make a function, fn : int -> int, which for an n > 0 finds the smallest m > n, such that m and n are *not* relative primes.
This is what I have made so far:

```
(* returns true if p,q are relative primes, else false *)
fun relativePrimes (1,q) = true
    | relativePrimes (p,q) = if p <> 0 then relativePrimes(q mod p,p) else false;
```

I use this function in

```
fun nextNotRelativePrime n = if relativePrimes (n,n+1) = false then n+1
    else if relativePrimes (n,n+2) = false then n+2 else n*2; (* and so on... *)
```

Problem here is that this function only works for n <= 9. Of course, I could extent it with more cases, but it will still not work for all n.

I need a way to increment n up by 1 for q (up to n*2) in relativePrimes (p,q) while p = n stays the same each time the function is called. I have no idea how though.

Comment: This is a hand-in assignment in the course *Introduction to Programming* at the University of Copenhagen. Please take the time to solve this yourself for better learning. You are not just ruining this for yourself, but for everyone who might stumble upon it. Use StackOverflow constructively and ask general questions -- that is very much encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement the search in a loop you need a helper function with the loop index as an additional argument.

As for the mathematical problem, the best way to solve it is as follows:

Find the smallest prime factor `p` of `m`, then let `n = m + p`.

To find `p` you can just use trial division up to and including the square root of `m`. If you don't find a factor then `m` is prime so `p = m`.

There are better methods for factoring a large `m` without small prime factors, e.g. [Brent's variant of Pollard's rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm#Variants).